# decltype for class method type

Tags: c++, decltype

I would like to store return value of class member function in another class.

This seems to work:

```
class Foo
{
public: 
   Foo(int) {} //non default constructor that hides default constructor
   unspecified_return_type get_value();


};

class Bar
{
    // stores a value returned by Foo::get_value
    decltype(Foo().get_value()) value;
};
```

However there is a reference to default constructor of class Foo, which may not be defined in some cases. Is there any way to do it without explicitly referring to any constructor?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yup, there is. [`std::declval`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/declval) was introduced for exactly this reason (not needing to rely on a particular constructor):

```
decltype(std::declval<Foo>().get_value()) value;
```

Comment: I was playing around with it, anyway it seems even OP's code doesn't call a default construtor... optimizations?

Comment: @MarcoA. Not optimizations. `decltype` is an unevaluated context (expresions are only evaluated for their type, but not actualy executed).

Comment: do I really need declval in this case then? If I just need the type I might get away without it

Comment: @MarcoA. The problem arises when the class doesn't have a default constructor (like the OP mentioned). I've added such a situation to his code example.

Comment: @MarcoA. You could get away with it. But the expression needs to be well formed anyway, so if it requires `DefaultConstructible` but could potentialy not be, then you need `declval`, yes.

Comment: @jrok I apologize on that edit. I got a little excited there. I've rolled it back... but there's no way to hide the shame of the fact I edited :(

Answer (score 5):

You could do it with the help of [`std::declval`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/declval) like the example below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>

struct test {
  int val = 10;
};

class Foo {
public:
   test get_value() { return test(); }
};

class Bar {
public:
  using type = decltype(std::declval<Foo>().get_value());
};

int main() {
  Bar::type v;
  std::cout << v.val << std::endl;
}
```

[<kbd>LIVE DEMO</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c8079e5de74e3010)

`std::declval<T>` converts any type T to a reference type, making it possible to use member functions in `decltype` expressions without the need to go through constructors.

`std::declval` is commonly used in templates where acceptable template parameters may have no constructor in common, but have the same member function whose return type is needed.